# What to do with code only Low Quality Post

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

I was having a look at the Low Quality Posts queue, and I was unable to figure out what to do with:

- an answer that has 1 or 2 lines of code and no explanation.
- other users have already commented under the answer in the hopes of an answer with added explanation.

Still, I am served the answer in the "Low Quality Posts" queue which is strange to me.

What route did this answer take to end up in the Low Quality Posts with already having feedback comments? How will it ever leave the queue if the answer never gets improved (i.e. what action do I take)?

Comment: Why is it strange to be in the queue? It is low-quality. The point of the queue is to either delete it, improve it or close it & get it immediately out of the queue. If it can only be improved by the author, vote to close it & when edited by the author well enough it can be voted open. See the priviledge info, meta.so & meta.se faqs & google those sites.

Comment: @philipxy You can't "close" answers.

Comment: Comment asking for clarification, downvote if you want, and press "Looks OK" if the code isn't taken from some other answer

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah, thanks, of course.